# Getting this error C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:conv_ops' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command

Tags: c++, tensorflow, machine-learning, feature-extraction, mediapipe

I am Trying to run Mediapipe Youtube 8m feature extraction graph and I am following these steps provided on this link https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/desktop/youtube8m

When I Execute this command

```
bazel build -c opt --linkopt=-s \
> --copt -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS --copt -DEGL_NO_X11 --define no_aws_support=true \
> mediapipe/examples/desktop/youtube8m:extract_yt8m_features
```

I am Getting this error

```
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:3809:18: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:conv_ops' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 180 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 180 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/youtube8m:extract_yt8m_features failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2371.506s, Critical Path: 1297.39s
INFO: 880 processes: 120 internal, 760 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I am running this code on Ubuntu 20.04.2 (Dual Boot)
intel i5 9th gen, Nvidia 1650 GPU 4gb

Python 3.8.10
Tensorflow-gpu 2.5
cuda 11
OpenCV 4 (made the required changes so as to support opencv4 mentioned in their doc)

Comment: Have you tried to use the `--sandbox_debug` or `--verbose_failures` options as suggested, to see more errors and messages? Then perhaps it can tell you more details about what's happening and why.

Comment: Yes i did that still shows the same no detailed message